# Read string as Level from csv

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a csv that looks like the following:

```
code         ,level,name        ,description
COM-0001,ERROR,Invalid Name,Name can not have digits
COM-0002,WARN ,Unusual Name,Name - {} was unusual
...
```

And I want to read the second (level) value as org.slf4j.event.Level .
I am using jackson-dataformat-csv library and not able to find an example that de-serializes the string ERROR, WARN etc into Level enums.
Here is what I tried:

```
 public static <T> List<Error> loadErrors() {
        try {
            CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
            CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
            File file = new ClassPathResource(errorFileName).getFile();
            MappingIterator<Fault> readValues =
                    mapper.readerFor(Error.class).with(bootstrapSchema).readValues(file);
            return readValues.readAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while loading errorlist from file " + faultFileName, e);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

And my Error POJO is as follows:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Error{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String description;
    //@JsonDeserialize(using = LevelConverter.class)
    @JsonProperty
    private Level level;

    public ERROR() {
    }

    public Error(String code, String name, String description, Level level) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.level = level;
    }
```

But I am getting the following JsonMappingException

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No enum constant org.slf4j.event.Level.WARN 
 at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 3, column: 15] (through reference chain: my.package.model.Error["level"])
```

Answer (score 0):

There was extra space after the WARN in the csv and I have to trim spaces using.

```
 mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES);
```